# bash -c "workon" return: "command not found"

Tags: bash, virtualenv

Using "workon" in bash result in list on envs.

```
bash> workon
project_1
```

When trying via bash -c, error is returned.

```
bash> bash -c "workon"
bash: workon: command not found
```

Edit 1: More information by comment

```
bash> type workon

workon is a function
workon () 
{ 
    virtualenvwrapper_load;
    workon "$@"
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information in the question. 
What is `workon`? `type workon` should tell you.

Comment: @Jakuje Thanks for mentioning "type". I have added the information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`workon` is a function. Function definition is local for a shell and not visible in the subshells (same as variables definitions).

You need to export the function, if you want to have it visible in subshells. From manual page for `bash`:

> `export [-fn] [name[=word]] ...`
>
> `export -p`
>
> The supplied names are marked for **automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands**.  If the **`-f` option is given, the names refer  to  functions**.   If  no  names  are given, or if the `-p` option is supplied, a list of names of all exported variables is printed.  The `-n` option causes the export property to be removed from each name.  If a variable name is followed by `=word`, the value of the variable is set to word.  `export` returns an exit status of 0 unless an invalid option is encountered, one of the names is not a valid shell  variable name, or -f is supplied with a name that is not a function.

Therefore `export -f workon` after function definition will solve your problems.